# bootstrap-datetimepicker not opened in spring boot

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, maven, spring-boot, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried use bootstrap-datetimepicker in spring boot app.
I included maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datetimepicker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I included links in my html file

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

And inserted

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ru'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open page I see [this](http://joxi.ru/brR5nMpFQaDwwA)

But when I press on data picker icon nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know enough about webjars, anyway if you are trying to use [this datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) you have to include both `bootstrap.js` and `moment.js` into your html, as explained [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

Comment: you need to add webjars-locator to your classpath for webjars to be served without a version, see [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content). Also the url is wrong